# Get data from cursor in SimpleCursorAdapter.getView()

Tags: android

I'm using implementation of `SimpleCursorAdapter`, which implements `SectionIndexer`. Here's part of it:

```
        public class MyAlphabetizedAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements
                SectionIndexer {
             public ContactAlphabetizedAdapter(Context context, int layout,
                    Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
               mIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(cursor, cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME), sAlphabet);
             }
             @Override
             public Object getItem(int position) {
                 if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_NORMAL) {
                     return super
   .getItem(position
                - mSectionToOffset
                .get(getSectionForPosition(position)) - 1);
                 }
                return null;
             }
        }
```

Inside getView(position) I need to access data from cursor for that position. How do I do it?

**UPD**

I'm using [this](http://eshyu.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/cursoradapter-with-alphabet-indexed-section-headers/#comment-80)  tutorial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  ...
  Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
}
```

Comment: Cursor is null after this call.

Comment: is there a reason you are implementing getItem? remove that and let the superclass get it